# Python starting and communicating with python subprocesses

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm in the process of planning out a system which will incorporate running and managing several python subprocesses whilst being directed by a web front-end. A top-level view:

```
Web Server -> Some kind of middle protocol -> master process on VM interprets message and starts python subprocess
```

I have a Mongo database setup for storing information about running processes so that the web front-end can query for status (managing this database would be the master processes responsibility).

I have most of the building blocks to make the above structure, but I have a few key questions before I continue:

1) What is recommended for filling in the 'Some kind of middle protocol' block?

2) Is there a Python framework already out there for automating most of what I'm trying to do?

Comment: [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) maybe?

Comment: Not the best question for SO, but I agree with @kalhartt. Celery is a good option.

Comment: I wasn't sure where the question would fit. I might be missing something here, but from what I can see it looks like there's no way to communicate to a VM running celery to start jobs or assign tasks. Am I missing something?